# pass array from matlab to c# via matlab com Automation service

Tags: c#, matlab, matrix

I tried to call some Matlab functions from C# code (`.NET`) using `PutFullMatrix()` & `GetFullMatrix()`.

I found that it worked well for passing arrays to the Matlab functions and finishing the calculation in the Matlab files.

The matlab files can also return the correct answer to C# when the return value is scalar (i.e. 1*1 matrix). But when I tried to return an 1*n matrix from Matlab to C#, it always ended up with an exception in Visual studio. It's a type of "System.Runtime.InteroServices.COMException" from mscorlib.dll.

I tried to simplify the function down to a matrix addition, still no luck. Can anyone shed light on why this fails? I am using .NET 4.5 runtime target for x86 CPU.

Below is my problematic C# code:

// Instantiate MATLAB Engine Interface through com

```
        MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
        matlab.PutFullMatrix("basebandData", "base", IData, QData);
        matlab.PutFullMatrix("sample_rate", "base",  SampleRateR,SampleRateI);

        // Using Engine Interface, execute the ML command
        // contained in quotes.
        matlab.Execute("cd c:\\Users\\****\\Desktop\\MatlabFunctionfolder;");
        matlab.Execute("open MATLABFunction.m");
        matlab.Execute("dbstop in MATLABFunction.m");
        matlab.Execute("[RespRate, HeartRate, HRWav, status]=MATLABFunction(basebandData,sample_rate);");

       // matlab.Execute("com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices.closeAll");
        matlab.GetFullMatrix("RespRate", "base", ref RespRateR, ref RespRateI);
        matlab.GetFullMatrix("HeartRate", "base", ref HeartRateR, ref HeartRateI);
        matlab.GetFullMatrix("HRWav", "base", ref HRWavR,ref HRWavI); // the line where the exception pop up, if don't try to return the array HRWav from matlab function (RespRate, HeartRate, and Status are all 1x1 matrices) the code services well. 

        matlab.GetFullMatrix("status", "base", ref StatusR, ref StatusI);
```

Comment: What exception is being thrown by Visual Studio?

Comment: a COMException: type of "System.Runtime.InteroServices.COMException" from mscorlib.dll. I am using .NET 4.5 runtime target for x86 CPU

Comment: If the problem still presists, how `StausR` and etc. are defined?